# Doctrine Select Listener in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, listener

I have an issue in Symfony getting a listener when selecting entries.
For example:

- A project has 2 entities: User and Product.
- A product is owned by a user.
- 3 different role of User: Admin, Owner and Reader

I want to add a listener which will allow to modify the DQL based on the User:

- If a user has an admin's role, there is no restriction
- Otherwise only the products owned by the current user can be selected.

The [DQL Hooks](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/event-listeners.html#dql-hooks) seems here to be right, but I found no documentation implementing it in Symfony

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Doctrine Filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/filters.html) in your case and register it in Doctrine bundle (if you use it) see [Filters Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#filters-configuration).

Also you can inject services needed in your custom Doctrine filter (for example Symfony Security service to check user permissions).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed the right solution. Nevertheless, the PDO does not allow to pass as parameter entities, such as user... and have to add the single info per string

Comment: What do you mean by PDO ?